# ExpressJS / AngularJS - sending progress messages from Express to $http.get()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

My `ExpressJS` application uses various APIs to parse data, and some of them can take quite a while. I'd like to send "update messages" to the browser while this is going on, so that the user knows that progress is happening.

I have a simple test app, set up like so:

`api.js`:

```
exports.test = function(req,res){
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function(id){
    i++;
    res.write("We're " + i + "/100th of the way there!")

    if(i === 100){
      res.send(200);
      clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, 200)

}
```

In my view:

```
<h1>{{httpMessage}}</h1>
```

In my Angular controller:

```
controller('testCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/api/test').then(function(data){
      $scope.httpMessage = data;
  });
})
```

This doesn't work, presumably because Angular's `$http` module is sending a request, and waiting for one success response before the `then()` callback function.

How can this be achieved then? With some sort of `socket.io` integration?

Comment: Browsers make the requests. You can't really make it work the other way. Websockets is one bidirectional method. The alternative is to have the browser periodically make requests to get the progress.

Comment: @sje397 do you have any examples of using websockets / `socket.io` in this sort of API call? I've seen some vanilla examples around with Express but none when routing through an API export...

Comment: You would need a websocket server on the other end, so I don't think it'll work with a standard express endpoint. Sorry I haven't played around much with websockets. Making periodic ajax requests from the browser is a pretty standard method though, although it does add overhead.